# VC++ 2019 folder location

Tags: visual-c++, cefsharp

I was reading [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#6-how-do-i-include-the-visual-studio-c-201220132015-redistributables-with-my-application) FAQ from Cefsharp and they refeer that I should copy over to my project the contents of this folder:

```
# Visual Studio 2015
# For VC++ 2015 (x86)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
# For VC++ 2015 (x64)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and VC+2019 and I can't find these folders.

Does anyone knows where I can find the required files?

Comment: Please read the FAQ item again in greater detail.

Comment: Could you point me to a direction? Due to deployment constraints, I need to copy the contents of Microsoft.VC140.CRT, but I can't find this folder on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the installation of `Desktop development with C++`.

After installing this I found the DLL's I was looking for here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.25.28508\x64`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.25.28508\x86`

Comment: Anyone with a GitHub account can edit the Wiki, you are welcome to add an additional dot point reminding users they need the C++ dev environment installed.

Comment: I will do it then!

Answer (score 0):

Following @Pedro Faustino's advice to install 'Desktop development with C++' (see screenshot), the `VC` folder can now be found in this path
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\`

[image: On the installation page for Microsoft visual studio, check the box which says 'Desktop development with C++']